# Calling one CLU(command line utility) with argument from another CLU in cmd ( youtube-dl from ffmpeg with additional arguments)

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, youtube-dl

I am able to run youtube-dl using command prompt , I have already kept youtube-dl.exe in the ffmpeg main folder and the ffmpeg bin folder and also I have kept ffmpeg.exe in the youtube_dl folder,

now I am trying to call ffmpeg.exe in command prompt from youtube-dl with some additional arguments in ffmpeg and vice versa with the below commands
and getting the following erros.

**Command**

```
C:\ffmpeg>youtube-dl -f 160 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3APNJYMrLo --hls-prefer-ffmpeg --external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args -ss 00:00:20 -to 00:00:30
```

**Command**

```
C:\youtube_dl>youtube-dl -f 160 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3APNJYMrLo --hls-prefer-ffmpeg --external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args -ss 00:00:20 -to 00:00:30
```

**Error**

```
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl: error: using output template conflicts with using title, video ID or auto number
```

and

**Command**

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:20 -to 00:00:30 -i "$(youtube-dl -f 160 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3APNJYMrLo)" -c copy youtube.mp4
```

**Error**

```
$(youtube-dl: No such file or directory
```

**Command**

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:20 -to 00:00:30 -i $(youtube-dl -f 160 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3APNJYMrLo) -c copy youtube.mp4
```

**Error**

```
$(youtube-dl -f 160 -g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3APNJYMrLo): Invalid argument
```

as per my understanding and the documentation pages of youtube-dl and ffmpeg the commands should work and should download the videos in the specified resolution but its not working.
Can someone guide me on this , what is wrong with the code and how to rectify it if any.

Comment: The cmd.exe shell does not produce the text output of a program using $() like ksh and bash do. If that is your intent, a `FOR` loop will be needed. Use the `FOR /?` command to read all about it.

Comment: @lit is there any utility in window with which i can achieve the desired functionality

Comment: Yes, there is. A `FOR` loop.

Comment: Hi I read and tried the following command after changing my directory to ffmpeg folder
**Command**
for /f "delims=" %i in ("youtube-dl -g https://video_link") do ffmpeg -ss 00:10:32 -to 00:10:38 -i "%i" -c copy output_file.mp4
**Command**
but still the command is giving an error -
**Command**
youtube-dl -g https://video_link : Invalid argument